# Django: Validate relationships among ForeignKeys

Tags: django, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have a model `Run` with two `ForeignKey`s, `signup` and `report`,

```
class Run(models.Model):
    signup = models.ForeignKey(Signup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="runs")
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="runs")
    kind = ...
```

pointing to models, which in turn are related to another model, `Training`,

```
class Report(models.Model):
    training = models.OneToOneField(
        Training, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True
    )
    cash_at_start = ....


class Signup(models.Model):
    training = models.ForeignKey(
        Training, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="signups"
    )
    participant = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="signups"
    )
```

When creating a `Run` I would like to make sure, that it's `signup` and `report` are for the same `Training`, i.e. that `report.training == signup.training`.

What is this kind of validation called? And how would I achieve it?

Also, I am happy to learn other ways to implement this, if another database structure would be better.

Comment: Can you explain why you have both `signup` and `report`, why not "merge" the two into a single model?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, there are more fields in the actual code. `Signup` describes a participant signing up for a `Training`, while `Report` captures the information of a `Training` taking place, e.g. how much cash was there at the beginning, and is only created, if a `Training` actually takes place (which requires a certain amount and some kinds of `Signup`). I tried to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) that describe the validation process on models.

Please note that this validation usually only happens with `ModelForms` (when calling `form.is_valid()`). Manually creating an object and using `save()` doesn't trigger this validation if you don't call `model_instance.full_clean()` method. It's aimed at the user, not the developer.

According to the mentioned docs, my suggestion is to use the `clean` method:

```py
class Run(models.Model):
    signup = models.ForeignKey(Signup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="runs")
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="runs")

    def clean(self):
        if self.signup.training != self.report.training:
            # Note: adding an error code is best practice :)
            raise ValidationError('some message', code='some_error_code')
```

**EDIT #1:** *Not using `ModelForm`*

You don't have to use the `ModelForm` to have validation on the model. Let's say you obtained `Signup` and `Report` instances from somewhere. Then you can instantiate and validate your `Run` instance like this:

```py
run = Run(signup=signup, report=report)
# Raises ValidationErrors
run.full_clean()
# If all is fine, call save
run.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect, I kind of kept seeing only Form validation ...

Comment: Unfortunately that `clean` won't work with forms that have excluded fields and I fill these fields in based on URL-Patterns, so they are not part of the form ... I could still overwrite `save` though, to check this.

Comment: Yes, that is the other option. However, keep in mind that when using `update` or `bulk_update`, `save` method is not triggered.

Comment: I added an edit to show how you could use this without the `ModelForm`

Comment: Oh indeed, I could just use any form  In the end I use `Run` even in a `FormSet`, adding quite a few DB calls and since it's filled in only in one place, I might also leave it at that. Thanks for your help!